# Custom checkout and SSL secure on every elements

Tags: theme, custom, ssl, https

My Magento store has a custom checkout.
We are currently trying to turn this checkout in https.
Everythings' gone well, but the fact that non checkout specific elements (such as menu and footer pictures) are not turned in https, so that the browsers send alerts.
Is there a specific base URL method or something that would turn all elements of the page in https ? It seems that Magento does it seamlessly on the standard theme...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using images in your header and footer they must specify that they need to be secure else they will just use the standard base url e.g for a secure image

```
$this->getSkinUrl('images/logo.png', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Remember, the header and footer get cached so they can't just be implemented on a certain page. You will need to specify them as secure all the time.

Another solution is to have a separate header and footer for checkout (which we always do) that uses the secure code above. Having checkout specific headers and footers is good for usability and minimizing abandonment.